# HIbernate/JPA Annotation Join ManyToOne with multiple columns but with conditional OR

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have these Entities

**Company**,**User**,**Project** and **Recommendation**

But what I want to highlight is the **Project** and **Recommendation** table.
Below is the entity sample.

```
//Project entity
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private String userId;

@Column(name = "company_id", nullable = true)
private String companyId;



//Recommendation entity
@Column(name = "id")
private String id;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private String userId;

@Column(name = "company_id", nullable = true)
private String companyId;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
@JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "company_id", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
private List<Project> projects;
```

Above tables are just illustration, sorry if that doesn't really make sense.
I want to join Project table inside Certification table.
They both are not directly related, so I need to join using these 2 columns, userId and companyId.

However, companyId is nullable. And whenever it is null, I still want to join the table only by userId.

What I want to achieve is probably along this line:

```
Select from Recommendation rec Join Project project 
on rec.user_id = project.user_id and (rec.company_id = project.company_id OR rec.company_id is null)
```

Is it possible to use hibernate / JPA annotations to achieve this?

My project uses Hibernate 5 recently

Comment: How about creating a View for your desired table?

Comment: Unfortunately, creating view is generally not allowed within my project and the use case is not critical enough for me to push that idea. Worst case, I probably going to use sql for this, or add extra logic in the service level.

Comment: You can create a projection and use the join in the query.
Can you add a query that you want to be able to execute?

Comment: Try use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.